# ZooKeeper zxid is used up due to data synchronization between the active and standby HBase clusters

Tags: hbase

During data synchronization between the active and standby HBase clusters, the active cluster frequently performs the setdata operation on ZooKeeper. Most znodes are in /hbase/replication/xxx format. As a result, the ZooKeeper zxid is exhausted and the ZooKeeper service is abnormal. Can the setdata operation be reduced?

Answer (score 0):

The HLog size is being increased to reduce the number of registrations with the ZooKeeper during active/standby synchronization.